# create-react-app is not working while adding dependencies

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i am running create-react-app u-survey commond and its giving me this

[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with npm. [You can track the issue here.](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17671)

The solution should be as simple as upgrading your npm version to `^5.6.0`.

You can upgrade using:

```
npm install -g npm
```

or

```
curl https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I was working with the react frontend app of the Microsoft MXChip IoT Dev Kit.

```
yarn install
```

[image]

The react app which I was using expecting the node version ">=4 <=9". But I was having the version "10.14.0", so I had to downgrade my node version. And I use [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) for the same, as mine is a windows machine. If you use Linux, you can use this [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

[image]

After switching to the lower version (8.14.0) I was able to perform install and build using yarn.

```
PS C:\Users\SibeeshVenu\source\repos\MXDial-IoT-Sample\frontend\mx> yarn build
yarn run v1.12.3
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (**Reactjs** project and **windows** platform) solved with:

```
npm install cross-env -g
```

and use `npm run` instead of use `yarn` to install or run the project.

I hope helpful